# how jenkins in a docker access git-repo of gitlab in another docker

Tags: git, jenkins, docker, gitlab

I installed both [gitlab-docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/gitlab/) and [jenkins-docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) on the same server(my laptop):

```
docker run --name gitlab-postgresql -d \
--env 'DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production' \
--env 'DB_USER=gitlab' --env 'DB_PASS=password' \
--volume /srv/docker/gitlab/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql \
quay.io/sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-5

docker run --name gitlab-redis -d \
--volume /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis \
quay.io/sameersbn/redis:latest

docker run --name gitlab -d \
--link gitlab-postgresql:postgresql --link gitlab-redis:redisio \
--publish 10022:22 --publish 80:80 \
--env 'GITLAB_PORT=10080' --env 'GITLAB_SSH_PORT=10022' \
--env 'GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=long-and-random-alpha-numeric-string' \
--volume /srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data \
quay.io/sameersbn/gitlab:8.0.5-1

docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -v /var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

in myjenkins docker ,use bash to run

```
git ls-remote -h ssh://git@localhost:10022/rhtj/yirongtong.git HEAD
```

or

```
git ls-remote -h ssh://git@10.0.0.131:10022/rhtj/yirongtong.git HEAD
```

which said:

```
ssh:connect to host localhost port 10022: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

and i have added the ssh pub-key to the gitlab,that can't work.
help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When  one container (using the default network bridge driver) needs to contact another, it does not need to use the mapped (to the host) port.

It will use directly the port exposed by the other container (here port 22).
If your jenkins container can run with a `--link` to the gitlab container, that will avoid having to use localhost or docker-machine ip and a mapped port: you will be using directly `gitlab-server:22`.